# Relation between Galois and etale cohomologies

Tags: nt.number-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $D$ be the ring of integers of a number field $F$. 
Let $X=\mathrm{Spec} ~D$, and let $\pi$ be the etale fundamental group of $X$.

There are natural maps from $H^i(\pi, \mathbf{Z}/n)$ to $H^i_{et}(X, \mathbf{Z}/n)$. Can you explain these maps?

Comment: An etale sheaf of sets on $X_{\rm{et}}$ restricts to the finite-etale site $X_{\rm{fet}}$ with exact left adjoint, defining a map of topoi $f=(f_{\ast}, f^{\ast}):{\rm{Et}}(X)^{\sim}\rightarrow{\rm{Fet}}(X)^{\sim}$. This yields a $\delta$-functor map ${\rm{H}}^i(X_{\rm{fet}},\cdot) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^i(X_{\rm{et}},f^{\ast}(\cdot))$ and so ${\rm{H}}^i(X_{\rm{fet}}, f_{\ast}(\cdot))\rightarrow{\rm{H}}^i(X_{\rm{et}},f^{\ast}f_{\ast}(\cdot)) \rightarrow{\rm{H}}^i(X_{\rm{et}},\cdot)$. For connected $X$, $X_{\rm{fet}}$ is the category of discrete left $\pi_1(X)$-sets. Evaluate on constant sheaves.

Comment: Let $S$ be a finite set of places of $F$ containing archimedean ones, $M$ a finite discrete module over $G_{F,S}:=\pi_1({\rm{Spec}}(O_{F,S}), \overline{F})$. The locally constant etale sheaf $F_M$ on ${\rm{Spec}}(O_{F,S})$ with generic fiber $M$ satisfies $f_{\ast}(F_M)=M$, so we have ${\rm{H}}^i(G_{F,S},M)\rightarrow{\rm{H}}^i({\rm{Spec}}(O_{F,S}), F_M)$ for all $i$. If $\#M$ is an $S$-unit, this is an isomorphism: due to Mazur for totally complex $F$, and (using that) T. Zink in general. See http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/Notes/L4.pdf (esp. App. A) for discussion and references.

Comment: In the preceding comment $F_M$ should have been denoted in some other way, say as $\mathscr{F}_M$, to avoid conflict with the use of $F$ to denote the number field in question.

Comment: For $i = 1$: There is an isomorphism $H^1(X,G) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{cont}}(\pi,G)$ for a finite group $G$, see [Lei Fu, Étale Cohomology Theory], p. 245, Proposition 5.7.20.